# How to make every character/line print in a random color?

Tags: python, colors, ascii

My wish is to make every character or line or whatever you think might look best for an ASCII to look. Basically I have tried `colorama` and it was only based on one color. What is the best method?

What I have is

```
print("""


   _____ _             _                        __ _
  / ____| |           | |                      / _| |
 | (___ | |_ __ _  ___| | _______   _____ _ __| |_| | _____      __
  \___ \| __/ _` |/ __| |/ / _ \ \ / / _ \ '__|  _| |/ _ \ \ /\ / /
  ____) | || (_| | (__|   < (_) \ V /  __/ |  | | | | (_) \ V  V /
 |_____/ \__\__,_|\___|_|\_\___/ \_/ \___|_|  |_| |_|\___/ \_/\_/




    """)
```

and that is pretty much it. Let me know your thoughts through this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The valid foreground colors provided by colorama are variables on `colorama.Fore`. We can retrieve them using `vars(colorama.Fore).values()`. We can random select a foreground color by using `random.choice`, feeding it the foreground colors as obtained by `vars`.

Then we simply apply a randomly-chosen color to each character:

```
text = """   


   _____ _             _                        __ _               
  / ____| |           | |                      / _| |              
 | (___ | |_ __ _  ___| | _______   _____ _ __| |_| | _____      __
  \___ \| __/ _` |/ __| |/ / _ \ \ / / _ \ '__|  _| |/ _ \ \ /\ / /
  ____) | || (_| | (__|   < (_) \ V /  __/ |  | | | | (_) \ V  V / 
 |_____/ \__\__,_|\___|_|\_\___/ \_/ \___|_|  |_| |_|\___/ \_/\_/  




    """

import colorama
import random

colors = list(vars(colorama.Fore).values())
colored_chars = [random.choice(colors) + char for char in text]

print(''.join(colored_chars))
```

This will print every character in a different color:

[image: color characters]

If you want colored lines instead, it's a simple change:

```
colored_lines = [random.choice(colors) + line for line in text.split('\n')]
print('\n'.join(colored_lines))
```

[image]

You can tailor the list of colors to your needs. For instance, if you want to remove colors which may be similar to your terminal background (black, white, etc.) you can write:

```
bad_colors = ['BLACK', 'WHITE', 'LIGHTBLACK_EX', 'RESET']
codes = vars(colorama.Fore)
colors = [codes[color] for color in codes if color not in bad_colors]
colored_chars = [random.choice(colors) + char for char in text]

print(''.join(colored_chars))
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Straight beautiful! Thank you very much!

Comment: I do wish I could removed just the black color because of the CMD but I think it will be fine :) If it is easy enough to remove the black one only. Would be awesome!

Comment: Oh. I do have the color for black now but how would that be possible to remove it in that case from the value? Is there a possible code for just removing instead of changing the whole line code? :)

Comment: Any set of colors can be used by modifying `colors`; see the edited answer.

Comment: Oh. Just when I entered the comment, I saw a edited 33 secs ago. Will check it @jme! I really do appreciate this really!