# print() outputs ASCII code + character instead of colored text

Tags: python, windows, cmd, colors, colorama

I took the reference of [How to make every character/line print in a random color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425645/how-to-make-every-character-line-print-in-a-random-color) and changed the text to ghost ASCII art but the output is not printing the colored art but printing ascii code + the symbols used in the **`text`**.

```
import colorama
import random


    
text = """
     .-----.
   .' -   - '.
  /  .-. .-.  \
  |  | | | |  |
   \ \o/ \o/ /
  _/    ^    \_
 | \  '---'  / |
 / /`--. .--`\ \
/ /'---` `---'\ \
'.__.       .__.'
    `|     |`
     |     \
     \      '--.
      '.        `\
        `'---.   |
              ) /
              \/
      """        
colors = list(vars(colorama.Fore).values())
colored_chars = [random.choice(colors) + char for char in text]
print(''.join(colored_chars))
```

Output :[image]

Comment: This works fine, *if* your terminal understands ANSI escape codes. The Windows command prompt is not such a terminal.

Comment: It looks lke your terminal emulator isn't interpreting the `ESC` character correctly, it's displaying a left-arrow instead.

Comment: I think you need to call `colorama.init()` after importing it.

Comment: @chepner: The latest versions of the Window command prompt *do* understand ANSI escape codes. See [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences)

Comment: I should have said "does not appear to be"; I don't use Windows myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `os.system('cls')` before printing to the console with colors.

Also include `r""` before your string to format it correctly (worked for me).

```
import colorama
import random
import os



text = r"""
     .-----.
   .' -   - '.
  /  .-. .-.  \
  |  | | | |  |
   \ \o/ \o/ /
  _/    ^    \_
 | \  '---'  / |
 / /`--. .--`\ \
/ /'---` `---'\ \
'.__.       .__.'
    `|     |`
     |     \
     \      '--.
      '.        `\
        `'---.   |
              ) /
              \/
      """

os.system("cls")
colors = list(vars(colorama.Fore).values())
colored_chars = [random.choice(colors) + char for char in text]
print(''.join(colored_chars))
```

Comment: That shouldn't have any effect on the escape sequences to display colors.

Comment: The point about using a raw string literal is valid, but nothing else here will fix the terminal's inability to understand ANSI escape codes.

Comment: It does for me, I have ran into this issue in the past on my own projects and clearing the screen works for some reason.

Comment: it works with this . i don't understand why few are saying no effect on escape sequences and terminals inability. Anyways the question is now closed with similar question which actually is not a similar question. Thank you.

Comment: Some are quick to jump to a conclusion based on their own understanding. In theory, just clearing the screen shouldn't work. But outside of my own understanding it just does and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Related [Colored text in command prompt after "cls" but not before "cls"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792323/colored-text-in-command-prompt-after-cls-but-not-before-cls).